# Click button to pass data from edittext to textview in the same page

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple program by put data in edit text to display in text view in the same activity.it is look like below image.

[image: android passing data program]

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView yourTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextviewId);
    EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourTextviewId);
    Buton yourOkButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourOkButtonId);

    yourOkButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                yourTextview.setText(yourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it works perfectly. But I have another question. If i want input "Hello/Hi" pass to two different textview(1. Hello. 2. Hi). How can i do this?

Comment: Please, explain better. Do you want to split the string "Hello/Hi" into two strings? "Hello" and "Hi" ?

Comment: Yes, I want it into two strings.

Comment: String string = "Hello/Hi";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
String hello = parts[0];
String hi = parts[1];

Comment: That just example. The real programm, the user input those two string by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(View view){
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** you can done like this :

```
yourButtonID.setOnClickListener
{
     
val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.yourTextViewID) as TextView
     
textView.setText(yourEditTextID.text.toString())
     
yourTextViewID.text!!.clear()

}
```